# Error compiling dts (Device Tree source) file for dtb

Tags: linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree, orange-pi

I've been trying to create a DTS file to utilize the GPIO pins, but I'm having trouble compiling the file.
I'm doing this on an orange.pi board, whose model is OrangePi-PC.
The code I used was the following:

```dts
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "allwinner,sun8i-h3";

    fragment {
        target = <&pio>;
        overlay {
            gpio_keys_user: gpio_keys_user {
                compatible = "gpio-keys";
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&gpio_button_0>;

                play_pause {
                    label = "Play/Pause";
                    linux,code = <164>;/*KEY_PLAYPAUSE*/
                    gpios = <&pio 0 7 0>; /* PA7 */
                };

                next {
                    label = "Next";
                    linux,code = <163>;/*KEY_NEXTSONG*/
                    gpios = <&pio 0 8 0>; /* PA8 */
                };

                previous {
                    label = "Previous";
                    linux,code = <165>;/*KEY_PREVIOUSSONG*/
                    gpios = <&pio 0 9 0>; /* PA9 */
                };
            };
        };
    };
};
```

When trying to compile the file through code:

```
dtc -I dts -O dtb -o gpio-keys.dtbo gpio-keys.dts
```

I got the following error:

```auto
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Property 'gpios', cell 2 is not a phandle reference in /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/play_pause
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Could not get phandle node for /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/play_pause:gpios(cell 2)
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Property 'gpios', cell 2 is not a phandle reference in /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/next
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Could not get phandle node for /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/next:gpios(cell 2)
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Property 'gpios', cell 2 is not a phandle reference in /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/previous
gpio-keys.dtbo: Warning (gpios_property): Could not get phandle node for /fragment/_overlay_/gpio_keys_user/previous:gpios(cell 2)
```

If anyone can help me I will be grateful.

Comment: "*I got the following error: ...*" - Those are not "*error[s]*", but rather warning messages (out of context). They're not fatal. The command should have generated an output file if those were the only (warning) messages.  What's the DTC version? (e.g. v1.4.5 is known to have issues.)

Comment: "*When trying to compile the file through code: ...*" - The *command* to generate a DT *overlay* would require the `-@` option in the dtc command line.

Comment: @sawdust I use version 1.4.5, just like you said, the files were generated on the desktop, but these messages made me question whether they were correct and functional.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the warning messages, then update to a more recent version of DTC, e.g. v1.6.