audio project with gpio buttons
Does anyone know of a method to use buttons connected to the GPIO of an Arduino board so that it starts audio from the file manager, I would also like the audio to pause, advance and rewind.
The Arduino model I use is the Orange.pi PC.
I tried using the OPi.GPIO and Pygame libraries, the first one was used to recognize the pins and I was successful in that. The second one was intended to program the desired function for the buttons, but I'm having difficulties, so I thought about looking for an easier method.
It's the first project I've done involving programming and Arduino, I didn't have a study prepared for this so I'm having difficulties, I hope you understand and if I can help I'll be very grateful.

If it runs Linux kernel, use gpio-keys driver, no code in C needs to be written. Ah, you are already on the right path, no need to duplicate you questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78212469/error-compiling-dts-device-tree-source-file-for-dtb.

@0andriy Sorry about that, now I don't know how to proceed after gpio-keys. I have the file but my python code gives an error on each line, I wanted an easy method instead of having to correct so many things, as each one is difficult to correct.

gpio-keys is a Linux kernel module which requires device tree to be updated. I don't understand how Python is involved here. In any case it's the correct method to go. Once you done, it can be used anywhere, without really thinking much about the code. In the user space you will simply get a key strokes as from (special) keyboard. PyGame already supports keyboards. No need to reinvent a wheel.

@0andriy So how do I configure the function of the buttons and put them into action? Through the code in the gpio-keys file?

I have published links in the comments to your first question, have you read them carefully? This file is Device Tree — it's not a kernel or user space code, it's special file to describe hardware, connected to the chip. This file should be compiled either as main platform description or as overlay. On the kernel side you should make sure that there is gpio-keysdriver available.

More links: https://uthings.uniud.it/control-gpio-pins-of-orange-pi-boards, https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=115394, https://github.com/fivdi/gpio-button/blob/master/README.md, https://www.rot13.org/~dpavlin/presentations/dc2018-linux_sensor_device-tree_shell_IoT.pdf. Read them all and gather necessary information.

@0andriy I read them, but I'm a layman so I didn't really understand what one of them was about, but thanks to the other link I managed to create gpio-keys. And reading these new links you sent I see another way to proceed, I appreciate your help. I will try to put it into practice and hope to succeed.

@0andriy Hi, I completed what the websites taught, they helped me with the use of Device Tree Source, but there is still one part left, where I configure the functions of the buttons, in this I must create a code, right?

Your buttons will generate a key codes, then you have a few options (also depending on the key codes themselves): 1) have your own libinput based listener and handler; 2) use existing daemons (like acpid for power button); 3) use existing listeners and handlers (like xinput from X). Depending on what you exactly want it may be code in shell, Python, C, or no code at all (if your buttons, for example, issue standard Play, Pause, Rewind codes and you want to use them vor VLC).

@0andriy Using VLC sounds easier to me, that's what I'll try.

@0andriy Returning here, I followed everything as I believe it should, but when I test the buttons using the "evtest" command, they don't work.

Probably you need to ask another Q with all code provided an steps you have done. It will be easier to get. The I believe it should is not a techincal term.

@0andriy OK I will do it
